# Getting an formula Prase Error while Merging Two Queries

Tags: google-sheets

I have merged the Two Queries to convert the 1 of the Column values (which are dates) into check and Uncheck.

If column has date it will be check anf if its empty it will uncheck.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({DATA!A3:BB},IF(ISDATE_STRICT(QUERY({(DATA!G3:G)})), "Check", "Uncheck")}, "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7", 0))
```

your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({DATA!A3:BB,IF(ISDATE_STRICT(DATA!G3:G), "Check", "Uncheck")}, "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7", 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to grab columns A to F and convert G column next to them, you may keep it more simple outside of the QUERY with curly brackets:

```
={DATA!A3:F,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(DATA!G3:G),"Check", "Uncheck"))}
```

Let me know!